# Размещение блоков, при уменьшении страницы

Tags: html, css

Вообщем нужна помощь, как сделать чтобы размещение навигации и логотипа, не смещалось при уменьшении страницы на _http://abans.shootline.ru/bans-384/ban_list.php

Answer (score 3):

Почитайте про [адаптивную верстку](https://www.google.com/search?q=адаптивная+верстка)

Answer (score 2):

[@bajex](/users/13072/bajex), для того, чтобы размещение навигации и логотипа не смещалось при уменьшении окна браузера/экрана, задайте для блока-обертки фиксированную ширину, например:

```
min-width: 1024px;
```

или

```
width: 1024px;
```